# Hosting XMPP server using docker on VPS with other containers?

Tags: docker, xmpp, reverse-proxy

I have a VPS with Portainer, NGINX Proxy Manager (NPM), and Jellyfin running in containers. I have plenty of ram and disk space to add an XMPP server in another container on the same VPS. I've had issues of installs not working when creating the server with Docker and trying to access it with a subdomain.

I know I'm being vague about the issues I've had. This should be a common use case. However, all the examples I find want you to build the reverse proxy but I already have that with the NPM container.

Am I just not finding the correct guides?

Comment: The thing with XMPP is that you may not need reverse proxy (it could work with WebSocket connections). Usually xmpp connections are on normal socket and don't require proxy inbetween.

Comment: Thank you for the information, @Wojtek. Okay. So I can understand. I currently have my *.domain.tld pointed to my VPS. If I want to use chat.domain.tld for XMPP, how would I direct traffic to the correct ports?

Comment: Using DNS SRV records: https://wiki.xmpp.org/web/SRV_Records and https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0368.html